# Automatically update a Debian system

Tags: debian, kernel, upgrade

I want to automatically update a Debian system (actually Debian Wheezy on Raspberry Pi, though that shouldn't make much a difference). I've already seen that there is `cron-apt`, probably a good choice, as it also includes mail notifications on errors.

I am however not sure about updates involving reboots like e.g. new kernel updates? Does `cron-apt` automatically reboot a system after a new kernel image was installed? Or can it at least notify me on update of specific packages?

Comment: No decent default configuration will automatically reboot, this could be extremely aggravating.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at `unattended-upgrades`. As this is run via cron you'll get emails after packages are updated. `unattended-upgrades` won't restart your system.

Comment: Thanks, I only want mails on errors and kernel updates, is that possible?

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf without any configuration, no. But look into apt-dater. You can also try to determine if the current running kernel is the latest one e.g . do the notification not via the upgrade mechanism but something else.